# Приложение с GUI на C#, а функционал на Python 3

Tags: c#, python, python-3.x, gui

Есть ли возможность сделать приложение с GUI, написанным на C#, а функционал на Python? Есть библиотеки и задачи которые будет в 14 раз легче написать на Python, но при этом нужен хороший современный GUI.

Comment: PyQt для Вас не является хорошим и современным средством разработки GUI?

Comment: @V-Mor, не понимаю, каким образом использовать стили для PyQt.

Comment: @АлександрБоканов `PyQt` поддерживает `CSS style sheets`

Comment: @nomnoms, дай бог здоровья, спасибо, нашел документацию по стилям

Comment: Ваш вопрос всё ещё актуален? Или использование PyQt подойдёт как ответ?

Comment: @V-Mor если "он" дал здоровья, то можно считать ваш комментарий как ответ

Comment: @V-Mor, вопрос актуален, но Qt пришел на рассмотрение как вариант. Горю желанием сделать свап Python и C#

Comment: Как-то сомнительно звучит. Тенденция последнего времени - gui на веб-технологиях, в частности, Electron. Даже сама Microsoft на это переходит.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, это вполне нормальная тенденция, которая даёт простоту в написании красивых, современных GUI, привлекающих глаз. Ты можешь использовать любой язык для этой нужды, не заморачиваясь о том, на чем писать интерфейс, потому что можно использовать те же HTML, CSS, JS, а функционал на Rust. Это прекрасно.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю альтернативное решение в виде использования PyQt для разработки GUI на Python.

Вот некоторые полезные ссылки: [для новичков в PyQt](https://pythonworld.ru/gui/pyqt5-firstprograms.html), [установка PyQt](https://pypi.org/project/PyQt5/), [документация](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/).